# menu de categorias, como hago para que salgan al lado del otro?

Tags: html, css, menu

como hago para que cuando aprete en categorias quiero que el test 5, 6 ,7 ,8, salgan al lado como muestra en la imagen, asi no se hace tan largo

aca les dejo el codigo https://codepen.io/sean_codes/pen/WdzgdY

```js
// For the thumbnail demo! :]

var count = 1
setTimeout(demo, 500)
setTimeout(demo, 700)
setTimeout(demo, 900)
setTimeout(reset, 2000)

setTimeout(demo, 2500)
setTimeout(demo, 2750)
setTimeout(demo, 3050)


var mousein = false
function demo() {
   if(mousein) return
   document.getElementById('demo' + count++)
      .classList.toggle('hover')
   
}

function demo2() {
   if(mousein) return
   document.getElementById('demo2')
      .classList.toggle('hover')
}

function reset() {
   count = 1
   var hovers = document.querySelectorAll('.hover')
   for(var i = 0; i < hovers.length; i++ ) {
      hovers[i].classList.remove('hover')
   }
}

document.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
   mousein = true
   reset()
})
```

```css
html, body{
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
   background:#191A1D;
   font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
   width:100vw;
}
body * {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}

/* HTML Nav Styles */
/* HTML Nav Styles */
/* HTML Nav Styles */
nav menuitem {
   position:relative;
   display:block;
   opacity:0;
   cursor:pointer;
}

nav menuitem > menu {
   position: absolute;
   pointer-events:none;
}
nav > menu { display:flex; }

nav > menu > menuitem { pointer-events: all; opacity:1; }
menu menuitem a { white-space:nowrap; display:block; }
   
menuitem:hover > menu {
   pointer-events:initial;
}
menuitem:hover > menu > menuitem,
menu:hover > menuitem{
   opacity:1;
}
nav > menu > menuitem menuitem menu {
   transform:translateX(100%);
   top:0; right:0;
}
/* User Styles Below Not Required */
/* User Styles Below Not Required */
/* User Styles Below Not Required */

nav { 
   margin-top: 40px;
   margin-left: 40px;
}

nav a {
   background:#75F;
   color:#FFF;
   min-width:190px;
   transition: background 0.5s, color 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
   margin:0px 6px 6px 0px;
   padding:20px 40px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   border-radius:3px;
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   position:relative;
}

nav a:hover:before {
   content: '';
   top:0;left:0;
   position:absolute;
   background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

nav > menu > menuitem > a + menu:after{
   content: '';
   position:absolute;
   border:10px solid transparent;
   border-top: 10px solid white;
   left:12px;
   top: -40px;  
}
nav menuitem > menu > menuitem > a + menu:after{ 
   content: '';
   position:absolute;
   border:10px solid transparent;
   border-left: 10px solid white;
   top: 20px;
   left:-180px;
   transition: opacity 0.6, transform 0s;
}

nav > menu > menuitem > menu > menuitem{
   transition: transform 0.6s, opacity 0.6s;
   transform:translateY(150%);
   opacity:0;
}
nav > menu > menuitem:hover > menu > menuitem,
nav > menu > menuitem.hover > menu > menuitem{
   transform:translateY(0%);
   opacity: 1;
}

menuitem > menu > menuitem > menu > menuitem{
   transition: transform 0.6s, opacity 0.6s;
   transform:translateX(195px) translateY(0%);
   opacity: 0;
} 
menuitem > menu > menuitem:hover > menu > menuitem,  
menuitem > menu > menuitem.hover > menu > menuitem{  
   transform:translateX(0) translateY(0%);
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <menu>
            <menuitem id="demo1">
                <a>drop</a>
                <menu>
                    <menuitem><a>about</a></menuitem>
               <menuitem>
                  <a>settings</a>
                  <menu>
                     <menuitem><a>Test 1</a></menuitem>
                     <menuitem><a>Test 2</a></menuitem>
                     <menuitem><a>Test 3</a></menuitem>
                     <menuitem><a>Test 4</a></menuitem>
                  </menu>  
               </menuitem>
                    <menuitem><a>help</a></menuitem>
                    <menuitem id="demo2">
                        <a>more</a>
                        <menu>
                            <menuitem id="demo3">
                                <a>deeper</a>
                                <menu>
                                    <menuitem><a>deep 1</a></menuitem>
                                    <menuitem><a>deep 2</a></menuitem>
                                    <menuitem><a>deep 3</a></menuitem>
                                </menu>
                            </menuitem>
                            <menuitem><a>test</a></menuitem>
                        </menu>
                    </menuitem>
                </menu>
            </menuitem>
         <menuitem><a>no drop</a></menuitem>
        </menu>
    </nav>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, yo estos días estoy trabajando con una jerarquía de categorías. No sabía que existían los tags HTML `menu` y `menuitem`. Con el poco sorporte que tienen y en contexto de uso, yo me pensaría mucho su uso: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_menu.asp https://caniuse.com/menu
Usa listas anidadas en su lugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas formas para eso, depende mucho de lo que necesites. Por ejemplo podes agregar este css:

```
/** básicamente cualquier menu hermano dentro de 
    de un submenu se coloca al 200% horizontal (porque
    cada columna ocupa 100%)
*/
nav > menu > menuitem menuitem menu + menu {
    transform:translateX(200%);
    top:0; right:0;
}
```

debajo de

```
nav > menu > menuitem menuitem menu {
    transform:translateX(100%);
    top:0; right:0;
}
```

y usar un nuevo menu para separar la nueva columna asi:

```
<menuitem>
   <a>settings</a>
   <menu>
      <menuitem><a>Test 1</a></menuitem>
      <menuitem><a>Test 2</a></menuitem>
      <menuitem><a>Test 3</a></menuitem>
      <menuitem><a>Test 4</a></menuitem>
   </menu>
   <menu>
      <menuitem><a>Test 5</a></menuitem>
      <menuitem><a>Test 6</a></menuitem>
      <menuitem><a>Test 7</a></menuitem>
      <menuitem><a>Test 8</a></menuitem>
   </menu>  
</menuitem>
```

Más allá de que funcione tené en cuenta que estarías perdiendo la posibilidad de que cualquier item de la primer columna (Test 1, Test 2. Test 3, Test 4) puedan incluir un submenu, porque el espacio a su derecha ya lo estas ocupando con la segunda columna y tampoco es extensible a una tercer columna (para esto deberías agregar otro bloque de css y usar otro valor en `translateX`).